# firebug and _moz_dirty

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, firebug

I am developing Javascript app that will wrap every line of text entered inside iframe (designmode) with P (or div) like it happens by default in IE.

For now I am not pasting my code because I just started, the first problem is when i type some text in firefox and even before I click enter or calling any function firebug inserts

```
<br _moz_dirty="">
```

under the entered text.

Why? How can I prevent it?

If you still need my code please tell.

Comment: I just noticed that too. It looks like it adds those to many tags, not just the `<br>`. Actually, probably all the tags that Mozilla adds. I suppose you need to either ignore those or remove them on Save.

Answer (score 1):

As the `_moz_`-prefix suggests, this is a Mozilla-internal property. It isn't inserted by Firebug, but rather by the core editor functionality in Gecko. You can't prevent it; ignore it or work around it.

Comment: first I want to understand what causes it.

Answer (score 1):

```
#myEditableDiv br {display:none;}
```

It's something Mozilla uses to prevent empty containers collapsing and occasionally inserts at seemingly random times too.

The question is, if they knew it was a dirty hack then why did they do it?

Comment: Why do we ever do dirty hacks?  To not get stuck on the trivial stuff.

Answer (score 1):

The `_moz_dirty` attribute is used to indicate that the node needs to be pretty-printed when the document is saved, although it shouldn't appear in web pages, only in SeaMonkey Composer and SeaMonkey and Thunderbird's HTML Message Compose.

Answer (score 0):

The Gecko editor used to put it there because it needed it to give it somewhere to put the cursor. I believe this is fixed in Firefox 4.

Comment: I'm getting the `_moz_dirty` attribute in Firefox 11

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were referring to the `<br>` tag.